# Understanding usage of slicing

Tags: python, slice

I am quite new to python and am trying to understand this code (from https://github.com/yoctoproject/poky/blob/master/meta/classes/insane.bbclass#L803 ):

```
a = b[:]
```

Why not rather use this simple form for copying a list?

```
a = b
```

Comment: Because `a = b` doesn't copy `b`, it simply makes the `a` object reference the `b` object. Later, if `b` is changed, the changes will show up in `a` as well.

Comment: @MattDMo ok thanks. Do you want to add this as an answer? or simply close?

Comment: I already closed it as a dupe. There's more in-depth explanations there.